# Kotlin fetch binary data using window.fetch API

Tags: javascript, kotlin, type-conversion

My goal is to implement Http request call in JS actual class of multi-platform project.

The http request should return a binary data

My **Response** common class looks pretty simple

```
class Response(val binaryData: ByteArray) {
    var code: Int = 0
    var message: String? = null
    var headers: Map<String, String>? = null
    var body: ByteArray = binaryData
}
```

the data should be provided as **ByteArray**

now the fetch logic looks like

```
actual class Call(var request: Request) {
    actual fun enqueue(responseCallback: Callback) {
        window.fetch(request.url).then(onFulfilled = { response ->
            response.arrayBuffer().then(onFulfilled = {
                responseCallback.onResponse(this, Response(it))
            }, onRejected = { error ->
                responseCallback.onFailure(this, Exception(error.message))
            })

    }
}
```

the **response.arrayBuffer()** has *ArrayBuffer* type whereas **it** in Response(it) should *ArrayByte*

I tried googling for a while. Unfortunately, I didn't find any solution.

Could anyone help me to cope with converting types problem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your porblem correct the proper solution might be build `Int8Array` from `ArrayBuffer` and cast it to `ByteArray` like this

```
Int8Array(it).unsafeCast<ByteArray>()
```